# How do I get a random number in template toolkit?

Tags: template-toolkit

I want to get a random number using template toolkit. It doesn't have to be particularly random. How do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [this post at Slashcode](http://ask.slashcode.com/article.pl?sid=02/06/17/0431216&tid=4):

```
[slash@yaz slash]$ perl -MSlash::Test -leDisplay
[%
digits = [ 0 .. 9 ];
anumber = digits.rand _ digits.rand _ digits.rand;
anumber;
%]
^D
769
```

Answer (score 7):

Hmm, you might have issues if you don't have (or cannot import) Slash::Test.
From a "vanilla" installation of TT, you can simply use the Math plugin:

```
USE Math;
GET Math.rand; # outputs a random number from 0 to 1
```

See [this link in the template toolkit manual](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Math.html) for more information on the Math plugin and the various methods.

Update: Math.rand requires a parameter.  Therefore to get a random number from 0 to 1, use:

```
GET Math.rand(1);
```